# iPhone OS 3.1.3 does not work with Xcode 3.2.1. Do I have to install SDK 3.2 BETA?

Tags: iphone, sdk, operating-system

Same as the title. Do I have to install SDK 3.2 BETA to work with OS 3.1.3?
I really want to avoid to install BETA on my main workstation. No other way?

I'm also thinking about rollback to OS 3.1.2 if there is no way. I'm regretting about I made no backup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vresion 3.1.3 of the iPhone SDK was posted to the iPhone dev center yesterday, install that and you should be back in business.

Don't install the 3.2 SDK unless you're going to be doing iPad development.

Answer (score 1):

You could always download the [3.1.3 XCode](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/download.action?path=%2Fiphone%2Fiphone_sdk_3.1.3__final%2Fiphone_sdk_3.1.3_with_xcode_3.2.1__snow_leopard__10m2003a.dmg).

Answer (score 1):

I put up a tutorial on how to get 3.1.3 working with Xcode 3.2

Check it out here http://chris-fletcher.com/2010/08/28/howto-install-iphone-sdk-2-0-3-1-for-xcode-3-2/

Comment: This answer could be improved by providing an exerpt from the article, in case that link changes someday - so that future searchers with similar problems don't wind up hitting a dead-end.

Answer (score 0):

No, iPhone SDK 3.2 beta just for iPad.

Answer (score 0):

A new 3.1.3 SDK was released yesterday (Feb 2 2010) Just log in to iPhone Dev Center and download it there.

Answer (score 0):

The 3.2 beta SDK is **not** compatible with iPhone OS 3.1.3 for development. To develop on 3.1.3, you **must** download the 3.1.3 SDK from the iPhone Dev Center.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:
Apple SDK Download site, download it and reinstall.
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action#downloads
Snow Leopard Downloads

```
* iPhone SDK 3.1.3 with Xcode 3.2.1
* iPhone SDK 3.1.3 with Xcode 3.2.1 Readme
```

---

Open your terminal. do it.

ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.2\ (7D11)/ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.3

---

Refrence:

iPhone OS 3.0 SDK and iPhone OS 3.0.1 software release for
Mac OS X v10.5.7
To continue development with iPhone SDK 3.0 on your iPhone, iPhone 3G and
iPhone 3GS running iPhone OS 3.0.1 will need to perform the following:
1. Log into your Mac with an Admin account and launch the Terminal application
(/Applications/Utilities)
2. Copy and paste the following line into Terminal:
ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0\ (7A341) /
Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1
Note: If you installed iPhone SDK 3.0 somewhere other than the default /Developer
location, replace the "/Developer" directory as appropriate.
© 2009 Apple Inc. All rights reserved. Xcode, Apple, the Apple logo, Mac, Mac OS, and Macintosh are
trademarks of Apple Inc., registered in the U.S. and other countries.
ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0\(7A341) /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

iPhone SDK Beta for 3.2 *has* 3.1.2 in it, Valery...you just have to choose that development environment.

I am using it now to write code for 3.1.2 .. I have not updated to 3.1.3.  I like to let new firmware sit for about a month before I update.